# Rendering private route after auth is complete does not work

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to setup a private route.

This is the return in my App.js

```
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <React.Suspense fallback={loading()}> 
                <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" render={props => <Login {...props}/>} />
                <Route exact path="/register" name="Register Page" render={props => <Register {...props}/>} />
                <Route exact path="/404" name="Page 404" render={props => <Page404 {...props}/>} />
                <Route exact path="/500" name="Page 500" render={props => <Page500 {...props}/>} />
                <Switch>
                  <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={DefaultLayout} />
                </Switch>
            </React.Suspense>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
```

This is my private route component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
  {...rest}
  render={props =>
    auth.isAuthenticated === true ? (
      <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      )
    }
    />
);

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

I think the issue is with the auth.isAuthenticated; when I change this to true === true, the correct component--DefaultLayout-- renders as designed.

However, when I console.log(this.props.auth), I get an error that says that this.props.auth is undefined.

**EDIT:**
I am receiving props when I re-write the component to be a class based component and console.log in the render portion. So, I believe that I am receiving props, and there is another issue.

I know what is going on with component: Component and ...rest, but I don't think I know what's exactly going on with auth when it's passed into private route.

I know that this.props.auth exists though, because when I console.log it in my Login compnent, I can see that a user is logged in and authorized.

Comment: Does the `mapStateToProps` in your `PrivateRoute` component match's with the `mapStateToProps` from `Login` component on how it extracts `auth` from the `store`?

Comment: @SultanH. yes, they're both done like this `const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, instead of:

```
<Switch>
  <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={DefaultLayout} />
</Switch>
```

Remove the `Switch` component that wraps the `PrivateRoute`, it can be preventing store from passing down to your `PrivateRoute`:

App.js:

```
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <React.Suspense fallback={loading()}> 
                <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" render={props => <Login {...props}/>} />
                <Route exact path="/register" name="Register Page" render={props => <Register {...props}/>} />
                <Route exact path="/404" name="Page 404" render={props => <Page404 {...props}/>} />
                <Route exact path="/500" name="Page 500" render={props => <Page500 {...props}/>} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={DefaultLayout} />
            </React.Suspense>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
```

Comment: I am receiving props when I re-write the component to be a class based component and console.log in the render portion. So, I believe that I am receiving props, and there is another issue.